# slidetoggle is executing 2 times on a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click to show a toggle, it executes 2 times and again closing the toggle thereby hiding my contents.Could someone please help on this.

Here is the code:

html:

```
 <div class="accordianbx"> 
        <div class="acc_icon">
            <div class="whyimgbx"> <span><img src="images/2.png" alt=""></span></div>
            <h3>abcd <span>&xyzs </span></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="hospital acc_descrpbx">
            <div class="innrleft_hospitalbx">
                <h2>desc </h2>
                <p>description</p>
                <a href="">&nbsp;Know More </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

jquery:

```
$('.acc_icon').unbind('click').click(function(){
        // alert('came into toggle function');
        $(this).parents('.accordianbx').find('.acc_descrpbx').slideToggle();

        $(this).parents('.accordianbx').siblings().find('.acc_descrpbx').slideUp();
        // alert('going out of toggle function');
    });
```

Comment: I think you need only this much :  `$('.acc_icon').click(function() {
  $(this).parents('.accordianbx').find('.acc_descrpbx').slideToggle();
});`.... check here and let me know:- https://jsfiddle.net/gychebpn/

Comment: As per you code `slideToggle` will execute first and then `slideUp` will execute so it will seen like executing twice

Comment: But I still have 4 more diva like the above..so when I click on one icon the one which is opened should be hidden and the clicked icon contents should be displayed..dats y v have 2 functions there...Also even if I comment on the second , I see the same issue

Comment: your code working fine here check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Udhaytitus/0rxbw1g5/4/

Comment: If I click on one icon, all other icon contents should be hidden and the one which I selected should alone be opened.

Comment: I see it is working fine in local. But when i deploy it in server, I see this issue

Comment: @LakshmiG : can you share the remote link ?